# Does case sensitivity have anything to do with strongly typed languages (or loosely typed languages)?

Tags: programming-languages, theory, case-sensitive, strong-typing

(I admit this may be a n00b question - I know very little about CS theory, mostly a hands-on/hobby sort.)

I was googling up strongly-typed language for the official definition, and one of the top links I found was from [Yahoo Answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100502140122AArbWvI), which suggested that case sensitive was a part of whether a language is loosely/strongly typed.

I had always thought the simple answer to the difference between a strongly typed/weakly typed language is that the first requires explicit type declarations, while the later is more open, even "dynamic".

The two S/O threads ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546960/strongly-vs-weakly-typed-and-statically-vs-dynamically-typed-languages-and-m) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690544/what-is-the-difference-between-a-strongly-typed-language-and-a-statically-typed-l)) I found so far seem to suggest that (more or less), but they don't mention anything about case sensitivity. Is there a relation at all between case sensitive and strong/weak?

Comment: Your source is a bad joke, much like: 
Q. Do you know why some computer scientists bang so hard on the keys when they type their programs?
A. They prefer STRONGLY TYPED languages!

Comment: wow, this was a really really old question from 7 years ago when i was mostly a php/javascript person

Answer (score 4):

A couple of clarifications:

1. Case sensitivity has nothing to do with strong vs. weak typing, static vs. dynamic typing or any other property of the type system. I don't know why the answer on yahoo answers has gotten its one upvote, but it's completely wrong. Just ignore it.
2. Strong typing isn't a well-defined term, but it is often used to refer to languages with few implicit type conversions, i.e. languages where it is an error to perform operations on types that do not support that operation.

   As an example multiplying the strings `"foo"` and `"bar"` gives `0` as the result in perl, while it causes a type error in ruby, python, java, haskell, ml and many other languages. Thus those languages are more strongly typed than perl.

   Strong typing is also sometimes used as a synonym for static typing.
3. A statically typed language is a language in which the types of variables, functions and expressions are known at compile time (or before runtime anyway - a statically typed language need not be compiled per se, though in practice it usually is). This means that if a statically typed program contains a type error, it will not run. If a dynamically typed program contains a type error it will run up to the point where the error happens and then crash.

Whether a language requires type annotations is (somewhat) independent of whether its type system is strong or weak or static or dynamic. In theory a dynamically typed language could require (or at least allow) type annotations and then throw runtime errors when those annotations are broken (though I don't know of any dynamically that actually does this).

More importantly there are many statically and strongly typed languages (e.g. Haskell, ML) that don't require type annotations, but instead use type inference algorithms to infer the types.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, case sensitivity is completely unrelated to type strictness.  Case sensitivity is about whether the *identifiers* `foo`, `FOO`, and `fOo` refer to the same variable, function, or what-have-you.  Type strictness is about whether *variables* have types or just *values* do, how easy it is to convert among types, and so on.

In practice, there might be a correlation between case sensitivity and type strictness, but I can't think of enough case-insensitive languages right now to make an assessment.  My impression is that most languages commonly used today are case sensitive — possibly because C was case sensitive and very influential, possibly because it was the only way to force people to stop PROGRAMMING IN ALL CAPS after a couple decades of FORTRAN, COBOL, and BASIC.

Comment: If there's a correlation, it's imperfect. For example, Pascal is more strongly typed than C (fewer implicit conversions, no untyped pointers), yet it's case-insensitive while C is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

No - they're not connected.  Strongly type languages force you to specify the type of data that a variable may hold - such as a real number, an integer, a textual string, or some programmer-defined object.  You they can't accidentally assign another type of data into that variable unless it is implicitly convertible: examples of this are that you can generally put a integer into a real number (i.e. `double x = 3.14; x = 3;` is ok but `int x = 3; x = 3.14;` might not be, depending on how strongly typed the langauge is).  Weakly typed languages just store whatever they're asked to without doing these sanity checks.  In strongly typed languages like C++, you can still create type that can store data that can be any of a specific set of types (e.g. C++'s `boost::variant`), but sometimes they're a bit more limited in how much you can do and how convenient it is to use.

Case sensitivity is means that the uppercase and lowercase versions of the same letter are considered equivalent for some purposes... normally in a string comparison or regular expression match.  It is unusual but not unheard of for modern computer languages to ignore the case of letters in variable names (identifiers).